# onEdit function does nothing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

*All the similar questions couldn't solve my issue.*

I have a **spreadsheet on google** and I'm trying to write **onEdit(e) function**.

I've just typed a simple code to log some text and variables:

```
function onEdit(e){
  Logger.log("Excuted");
  var spreadsheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var activeCol = e.range.getColumn();
  var activeRow = e.range.getRow();
  Logger.log(activeRow + activeCol + spreadsheet);
}
```

Wherever I edit in the sheet nothing is logged.

I go to the editor and click run, the logger then shows this output:
[image: Logger output after running the script.]

**Why the edit event is not triggered?**

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e){
  const msg=Utilities.formatString('Row: %s, Col: %s SheetName: %s',e.range.rowStart, e.range.columnStart, e.range.getSheet().getName());
  e.source.toast(msg);
}
```

Note: this function requires a onedit trigger event object so it cannot be run from menu or from the script editor.  Just save it in the script editor and go edit some pages.